# What is the syntax error in this line of code in Odoo

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

I am kind of newbie to python and odoo and am getting invalid syntax error in the following line of code

```
template_id = self.pool.get('email.template').search(cr, uid, [('name','=ilike',Meeting Invitation)])
```

Can anyone please kindly help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use quotes around *Meeting Invitation* and you should pass the *context* as a parameter to the `search` method:

```
template_id = self.pool.get('email.template').search(cr, uid, [('name', '=ilike', 'Meeting Invitation')], context)
```

Comment: Thank you very much forvas ...:)